# UIPickerView - Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a custom cell that either display a numberPicker or a timePicker. The cell will properly display the numberPicker, but crashes every time I try to display the timePicker. I've put in breakpoints, and it crashes right after I set the datasource in awakeFromNib:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    if timePicker != nil {
        timePicker.delegate = self
        timePicker.dataSource = self <-- After this the crash occurs
    }

    if numberPicker != nil {
        numberPicker.delegate = self
        numberPicker.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

The complete code for setting up the UIPickerView is as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var numberPicker: UIPickerView!

var times:[[Int]] = [[Int](0...59), [Int](0...59)]
var nums: [Int] = Array(0...100)

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    if timePicker != nil {
        timePicker.delegate = self
        timePicker.dataSource = self
    }

    if numberPicker != nil {
        numberPicker.delegate = self
        numberPicker.dataSource = self
    }
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    if pickerView == numberPicker {
        return 1
    } else {
        return 2
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView == numberPicker {
        return nums.count
    } else {
        return times[component].count
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == numberPicker {
        return String(nums[row])
    } else {
        return String(times[component][row])
    }
}
```

I've tried deleting derivedData and cleaning my build multiple times, and that doesn't help either. Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does your class conform to UIPickerViewDataSource? Maybe thats the problem

Comment: @glace yes it does. Thanks for checking though!

Comment: Check your IB outlets. Chances are one of them isn't connected - so is nil at runtime.

Comment: IB Outlets are connected as well, but good suggestion!

Comment: The problem is most likely the way how those outlets are initialized. Since they are declared with UIPickerView!, they won't be nil at any given time. My suggestion is to think of another way of checking which one to show instead of (pickerView != nil)

Comment: Any update on this?